# Increment a document using find $in array

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to increment a certain document using $in array, .... first I have to find an item mathcing inside the array, my problem here is.. when the array has same item, it does not increment the item,like this:

```
newFruits = ['orange','orange','orange'];
Fruits.find({{fruit: { $in : newFruits}}}, function(err, fruitDocs) {

    for(let fruits of fruitDocs) {
       fruits.value = fruits.value + 1
       fruits .save(function(err) {});
    }  
});
```

**Sample Document:**

```
fruit:orange,
value:0     //this should be 3 since the array is composed of 3 orange
            //but when I try to increment it only increment once

fruit:apple,
value:0
```

Comment: You have already asked a question about this and you have a response telling you that specifying multiple occurrences to `$in` will not retrieve/update the same document multiple times. Instead of posting new questions, please clarify in your original question what you intend to do.

Comment: I dont have any answer can you help me here please

Comment: Just because you don't have an answer to a question is no reason to ask the same thing again. I actually just asked you to [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55232808/edit) with details that you were actually asked for within the comments on that question. Provide more detail there and you'll probably get an answer showing you how to do what you actually need to do.

Comment: To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it. Read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).